# Exception caught by image resource service, setState() called after dispose(): _ImageState

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

[image]

This error occurs if i switch the page while the image is still loading. And it does not trigger a reload either if i return to the page. 
I dont get it, isnt the whole point behind using the loadingBuilder, frameBuilder and errorBuilder to avoid such a scenario? Shouldn't the dispose/reload be handled automatically this way? 
Did i use the Image.network the right way or is my approach itself wrong?

I also tried assigning the `Image.network` to `Image _image` in `init` state, and then trying to close/dispose/unmount in the `dispose` method but none of the methods are available.

```
Image.network(
      widget.url,
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      frameBuilder: (
          BuildContext context,
          Widget image,
          int frame,
          bool wasSynchronouslyLoaded,
          ) {
        return AnimatedOpacity(
          child: image,
          opacity: frame == null ? 0 : 1,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
          curve: Curves.easeIn,
        );
      },
      loadingBuilder: (
          BuildContext context,
          Widget image,
          ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress,
          ) {
        if (loadingProgress == null) return image;
        if (loadingProgress != null &&
            loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded <
                loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else if (loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded ==
            loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes) {
          return image;
        }
        return image;
      },
      errorBuilder:
          (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            '${exception.toString()}',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    )
```